# Create pyside application in different shape than rectangle

Tags: python, pyside2

I am building an application in Pyside2.

As we know when we use mainwindow for our application it comes with rectangle shape.

But I want user define shape of application.

For example check below image of Zoiper application.

[image]

The background is my editor with some text, You can easily feel the outer border of application.

Can we achieve the same thing using pyside2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a transparent widget. Two lines are important:

```
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Tool)
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

Working example:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QPainterPath, QPainter
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class WCustomShape(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Tool)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addEllipse(200, 150, 100, 50)
        painter.fillPath(path, QColor(Qt.blue))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = WCustomShape()
    main_window.show()
    main_window.raise_()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```